# Joining on date ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, inner-join

I have 2 tables in SQL Server.  One has daily date and the other has some dates on which a change was applied.  This change needs to be copied over in the first table.  Sample data is:

**TABLE TARGET**

```
Date_                   | name | value
---------------------------------------
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 | msft | NULL
2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 | msft | NULL
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 | msft | NULL
2011-11-01 00:00:00.000 | amzn | NULL
2011-11-02 00:00:00.000 | amzn | NULL
2011-11-03 00:00:00.000 | amzn | NULL
2011-11-04 00:00:00.000 | amzn | NULL
```

**TABLE SOURCE**

```
Date_                   | name | value
---------------------------------------
2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 | msft | 100
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 | msft | 200
2011-11-01 00:00:00.000 | amzn | 50
```

What I need :

**FINAL TABLE TARGET**
    Source table values need to be updated such that all dates greater than or equal to in the target table dates are updated with the corresponding value. Final Target table should look like:

```
Date_                   | name | value
----------------------------------------
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 | msft | 100
2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 | msft | 100
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 | msft | 200
2011-11-01 00:00:00.000 | amzn | 50
2011-11-02 00:00:00.000 | amzn | 50
2011-11-03 00:00:00.000 | amzn | 50
2011-11-04 00:00:00.000 | amzn | 50


/* 
-- Code
create table #Target (date_ datetime, name varchar(10), value float) create table #Source (date_ datetime, name varchar(10), value float)
insert into #Target  select '1/1/2011', 'msft', NULL insert into #Target  select '1/2/2011', 'msft', NULL insert into #Target  select '1/3/2011', 'msft', NULL insert into #Target  select '11/1/2011', 'amzn', NULL insert into #Target  select '11/2/2011', 'amzn', NULL insert into #Target  select '11/3/2011', 'amzn', NULL insert into #Target  select '11/4/2011', 'amzn', NULL
insert into #Source select '1/1/2004', 'msft', 100 insert into #Source select '1/3/2011', 'msft', 200 insert into #Source select '11/1/2011', 'amzn', 50
select * from #Target select * from #Source drop table #Target drop table #Source
*/
```

What has been tried so far:

```
create table #mysource (startdate datetime, 
                        name varchar(10), 
                        value float, 
                        rowid int, 
                        enddate datetime)

insert into #mysource (startdate,name,value) 
select date_,name,value 
from #source 

update  #mysource set rowid = subq.RowID 
FROM    #mysource 
inner join (SELECT  date_, name, RowId=Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_) 
from #Source) AS subq on subq.date_ = #mysource.startdate AND subq.name = #mysource.name
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? I don't see any where clauses anywhere

Comment: @brad You mean how I completed Final Table Target? I completed it manually. Looking for a SQLServer code.  I tried partition by and rowids. Can make it work but it looks like a very dirty solution.

Comment: correct. The attempt that made you say "that's enough trying this! I need the internet". That step should be posted here, too.

Comment: Right, so far, it looks like you just said "this is what I want, someone do it for me." without trying it for yourself...

Comment: guys.. this is where im as of now. I don't want to loop it over rowids. It won't be a good solution unless that is my only option. Can you stop judging why this question was asked? I spent more time typing it and so quite sure about my SQL limitations when i posted it.  My current code is given below.  Would appreciate your help.

Comment: create table #mysource (startdate datetime, name varchar(10), value float, rowid int, enddate datetime) 
 insert into #mysource (startdate,name,value) select date_,name,value from #source

 update #mysource
 set  rowid = subq.RowID
 FROM #mysource
   inner join (SELECT date_, name, RowId=Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_) from #Source) AS subq on subq.date_ = #mysource.startdate AND subq.name = #mysource.name

Comment: Sorry, I don't think we were trying to judge, just asking for more information on what you have already tried.  Thanks for adding what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be a sub-select on the source table but only take the top one ordered by the date descending. Like so:

```
UPDATE #Target SET value = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM #source s WHERE s.name = t.name AND s.Date_ <= t.Date_ ORDER BY s.Date_ DESC)
FROM #Target t
```

And note: it'd be a better test case if the dates overlapped. i.e. all the months were either 01 or 11 rather than a mix.

Answer (score 0):

The query that Jacob posted works great.  Basically, it will update the `value` to whatever the most recent `value` is in the `source` table that is less than the `date_` in the `target` table for the given `name`.

Here is a link to an SQL fiddle with a working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20983/1